# Share VirtualEnv with team members in Pycharm

Tags: python, pycharm

## Background

Using Pycharm, I've created a Run/Debug Configuration and selected `Store as project file`. The generated `.run` folder is committed to source control and share with the team. See [sharing configurations](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/run-debug-configuration.html#share-configurations) in Pycharm's docs.
However, those configurations include `Python interpreter` which should be taken from a virtualenv.

## The problem

The `Python interpreter` is OS and machine depended and setting it up requires a few different steps.

## The question

How can I share the virtualenv with other team members to use the configurations in `.run` folder without them needing to manually run `pip install`?

## Things tried

As answered in many other questions, such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34993200/copy-complete-virtualenv-to-another-pc), [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57494274/is-is-possible-to-share-a-virtualenv-across-machines) and [that one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34210300/syncing-virtualenvs-in-multiple-computer), I use `pip install` inside the Run Configuration to set-up the virtualenv. However, the `pip install` requires steps that are:

1. OS specific
2. Same for every user, so why repeat on every machine?